# dismissModalViewAnimated actually removes parent view

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have an application that allows a user to add a picture to a log.
If the user chooses to add from library, everything is fine, but if a user chooses to take
a picture with the camera there's an issue:

When the camera modal view is animated in and I either take a picture and tap on "Use" or i click on the "Cancel" button, the view I'm in when calling dismissModalViewAnimated is removed from its superview.

Anyone got an explanation for this?

Here's the code I use for presenting the modal viewcontroller

```
pickerCont = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
pickerCont.delegate = self;
pickerCont.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentModalViewController:pickerCont animated:YES];
```

And this is what i use to dismiss it:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

Comment: Please show more of your code and are you using the DLCImagePickerController ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are dissmissing parentview. here **self** represents parentView

Use UIImagePickerController's delegate to dissmiss UIImagePickerController

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
   //get picked image here

   [pickerCont dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]

}
```

Comment: How right you are! I thought I'd already tried that solution, but it seems I re-init'ed the pickerCont and then tried [pickerCont dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES] :-S

Thanks for opening my overworked eyes, Prince!